# What is the difference between .catch and .fail in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, promise, deferred

The short doc for `.fail` says:

> Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is rejected.

and the short doc for `.catch` is exactly the same:

> Add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is rejected.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

The arguments accepted by the two methods seem to be different, and the doc of
`.catch` states that `.catch` is an alias of `.then(null, fn)`

Are there cases where I should use `.fail` and others where I should use `.catch`?

Or ... if I only have one function ... are following commands interchangeable  and they only exist for compatibility/historical reasons?

```
a) .fail(fn)

b) .catch(fn)

c) .then(null, fn)
```

I created a jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/sq3mh9j5/

If there is a difference, could you please provide some examples since I am new to jquery and not yet familiar with all promise terms.

Why does the doc of .catch does not reference the doc of .fail and clarify the difference/similarity?

**Edit**
I found some notes in the 3.0 release notes that the behavior of .then changed.
https://blog.jquery.com/2015/07/13/jquery-3-0-and-jquery-compat-3-0-alpha-versions-released/
Nevertheless I am still unsure when to use .fail and when to use .catch.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`catch` and `fail` are slightly different, in that `catch` will return a new (resolved) promise, whereas `fail` will return the original promise.

```
// This will only output "fail"
$.Deferred()
  .reject(new Error("something went wrong"))
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("fail");
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log("then after fail");
  })
```

```
// This will output "catch" and "then after catch"
$.Deferred()
  .reject(new Error("something went wrong"))
  .catch(function() {
    console.log("catch");
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log("then after catch");
  })
```

[Note that `catch(fn)` is an alias of `then(null, fn)`.](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.catch/)

Comment: "*will re-resolve the promise*" is quite misleading. The important point is that it returns a new, distinct promise (just like `then`).

Comment: Ah, got it. I didn't quite know how to describe it - I'll update my answer. Thanks

Comment: So if I want to `break/exit` the normal workflow on error... I'll use `fail` (first example)  and if I want to implement an `always` clause I use a then after `catch` (second example).

Comment: @Stefan I recommend to simply never use `fail` and `done`.

Answer (score 3):

So I think the major difference is what you get out of each.

A catch allows you to run a single function.

A fail allows you to run a number of functions.

Other than that I concur with your findings. They are very similar.

I added an example code to showcase how fail will run both functions, and the catch will only run the one.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "abc"
        }).done(function (data) {

        }).fail(function () {
            alert("a");
        }, function () {
            alert("b");
        })
                .catch(function () {
                    alert("c");
                }, function () {
                    alert("d");
                });
```

If you run this you get 'a','b','c' and then 'd' doesn't run.

I hope this simple example showcases the difference.